# Set old value of select2 of two same inputs

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to set the old value of the two same inputs in laravel blade.
the first div works properly but the second one not working.

note: the request of update method is

```
'parent_id' => $request->council_parent_id,

 'parent_id' => $request->parent_id,
```

[this one render the old value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jcOg.png)
[but this one is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu9PY.png)

```
<div class="form-group parent_id">
{{ Form::label('parent_id', 'اختر اللجنة الرئيسية', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
{{ Form::select('parent_id', $parents, \Input::old('parent_id') , ['placeholder' => '','class' => 'form-control parent_id select2d']) }}
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('parent_id') }}</span>
```

```
<div class="form-group council_parent_id">
{{ Form::label('council_parent_id', 'اختر المجلس الرئيسي', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
{{ Form::select('council_parent_id', $council_parents,\Input::old('parent_id') , ['placeholder' => '','class' => 'form-control council_parent_id select2', 'value' => $mainCouncil]) }}
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('parent_id') }}</span>
```

Comment: in your 2nd one you have `value => ...` and also try to set the value via `\Input::old`

Comment: you mean delete value?

Comment: yes try doing that and in the 3rd paramenter try `\Input::old('parent_id', $mainCouncil)`

Comment: thanks for your reply but it still not working bro

Comment: still not appear

Comment: is the `parent_id` option in `$council_parents` ?

Comment: no it is the name of the record in database

Comment: the value needs to exist in the options of the dropdown to be selected. The second parameter of `Form::select` would be of the form `[ <value> => <label> ]` to create options like `<option value="<value>"><label></option>` and the selected option would be the one with a value given by the 3rd parameter

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing. It's done -apokryfos by:

```
\Input::old('parent_id', $mainCouncil)

<div class="form-group council_parent_id">
{{ Form::label('council_parent_id', 'اختر المجلس الرئيسي', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
{{ Form::select('council_parent_id', $council_parents,\Input::old('council_parent_id', !empty($mainCouncil->id) ? $mainCouncil->id:''), ['placeholder' => '','class' => 'form-control council_parent_id select2']) }}
<span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('council_parent_id') }}</span>
```